# Arranging data in an text document using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file called `data.txt` which contains the following information in it

```
03/05/2016 11:00  50
03/05/2016 11:11  10
03/05/2016 11:20  30
03/05/2016 11:33  40
03/05/2016 11:40  40
03/05/2016 11:50  50
03/05/2016 11:60  70
03/05/2016 12:00  25
03/05/2016 12:10  69
03/05/2016 12:12  25
03/05/2016 12:30  59
03/05/2016 12:44  25
03/05/2016 12:54  29
03/05/2016 12:60  25
```

I want the output to be like this. This data should be stored in another file named `reslt.txt`

```
03/05/2016 11:00 - 12:00 290
03/05/2016 12:00 - 13:00 257
```

The 3rd column in `reslt.txt` file is sum of values of 3rd column in `data.txt` file. I am using python 2.7

How can i achieve this guyz

(UPDATED)
Things i have tried

```
from collections import Counter
import re

with open('data.txt') as f:
    res = sum((Counter({x.group(1): int(x.group(2))})
               for x in (re.search('(.*?):.*\s(\d+)', line) for line in f) if x),
              Counter())

with open('reslt.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines('{0}:00 - {1}:00 {2}\n'.format(k, int(k.split()[-1]) + 1, v)
                 for k, v in sorted(res.iteritems()))
```

but i aint getting any output

**(UPDATE)**
additional input file

```
07/05/2016 19:27  0.00169
07/05/2016 19:28  0.0034
07/05/2016 19:29  0.0051
07/05/2016 19:30  0.00679
07/05/2016 19:31  0.0085
07/05/2016 19:32  0.01021
07/05/2016 19:33  0.0119
07/05/2016 19:34  0.01358
07/05/2016 19:35  0.01527
07/05/2016 19:36  0.01696
07/05/2016 19:37  0.01863
07/05/2016 19:38  0.02031
07/05/2016 19:39  0.02199
07/05/2016 19:40  0.02367
07/05/2016 19:41  0.02535
07/05/2016 19:42  0.02704
07/05/2016 19:43  0.02871
07/05/2016 19:44  0.03039
07/05/2016 19:45  0.03207
07/05/2016 19:46  0.03376
07/05/2016 19:47  0.03544
07/05/2016 19:48  0.03712
07/05/2016 19:49  0.0388
07/05/2016 19:50  0.04049
07/05/2016 19:51  0.04217
07/05/2016 19:52  0.04386
07/05/2016 19:53  0.04555
07/05/2016 19:54  0.04723
07/05/2016 19:55  0.0489
07/05/2016 19:56  0.05057
07/05/2016 19:57  0.05225
07/05/2016 19:59  0.05392
07/05/2016 20:00  0.05561
07/05/2016 20:01  0.05729
07/05/2016 20:02  0.05897
07/05/2016 20:03  0.06067
07/05/2016 20:04  0.06234
07/05/2016 20:05  0.06403
07/05/2016 20:06  0.06571
08/05/2016 20:07  0.06739
08/05/2016 20:08  0.06908
09/05/2016 20:09  0.06994
09/05/2016 20:10  0.06994
10/05/2016 20:11  0.06994
10/05/2016 20:14  0.01614
11/05/2016 19:24  0.00197
11/05/2016 19:26  0.01746
```

Comment: Dont simply down rate me

Comment: I don't understand where the third column comes from? How do you get to the numbers 290 and 257? What numbers are adding? Give an example like (50+50+50+50 = 200)

Comment: from 11:00 to 12: 00 i.e 50+10+30+40+40+50+70 = 290

Comment: @Keatinge this is how i summed up

Comment: @Keatinge please help me out sir

Comment: Please show the directory listing you have.  When I run this, **reslt.txt** is exactly as expected.  You *do* realize that this code doesn't print anything to the console, I hope: the output is in **reslt.txt**.

Comment: @Prune resly.txt is blank

Comment: Okay ... weird ... I backed up until I got the output printed to the console, couldn't find the problem, and finally reverted to your original code.  It works for me.

Comment: Your new input has decimal points so your regex needs to account for that (it only accepts digits) and you need to use float instead of int.

Comment: @AlexHall dosent work sir , tried it

Comment: It works here: http://ideone.com/Fyw2MB

Comment: @AlexHall, I reproduced your success in my environment.  The critical addition is the period inserted into the regexp's **([\d.]+)** clause.

Comment: @AlexHall thanks ... my edit is corrected ... I think ...

Comment: Hey, do you have consistent separators here (like \t or , by chance?) also, are some of the time columns actually presented as 11:60 instead of 12:00, etc. (as is the case in your first example)?

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps you at all, here's the most compact form of my debugging run.  Your original code works fine for me, but this may help you diagnose your problem.

```
from collections import Counter
import re

with open('data.txt') as f:
    res = sum((Counter({x.group(1): int(x.group(2))})
               for x in (re.search('(.*?):.*\s(\d+)', line) for line in f) if x),
              Counter())

print res

with open('reslt.txt', 'w') as f:
# Write to console
    for k, v in sorted(res.iteritems()):
        print k, '||', v
        print k, '--', int(k.split()[-1]) + 1, '--', v

# Write to file
    f.writelines('{0}:00 - {1}:00 {2}\n'.format(k, int(k.split()[-1]) + 1, v)
                 for k, v in sorted(res.iteritems()))
```

reslt.txt:

```
03/05/2016 11:00 - 12:00 290
03/05/2016 12:00 - 13:00 257
```

Comment: 07/05/2016 19:46  0.03376
07/05/2016 19:47  0.03544
07/05/2016 19:48  0.03712
07/05/2016 19:49  0.0388
07/05/2016 19:50  0.04049
07/05/2016 19:51  0.04217
07/05/2016 19:52  0.04386
07/05/2016 19:53  0.04555
07/05/2016 19:54  0.04723
07/05/2016 19:55  0.0489
07/05/2016 19:56  0.05057
07/05/2016 19:57  0.05225
07/05/2016 19:59  0.05392
07/05/2016 20:00  0.05561
07/05/2016 20:01  0.05729
07/05/2016 20:02  0.05897
07/05/2016 20:03  0.06067
07/05/2016 20:04  0.06234
07/05/2016 20:05  0.06403
07/05/2016 20:06  0.06571